# Unable to save JSON data from Alamofire GET request to local variables of function

Tags: ios, json, swift, get, alamofire

I'm trying to save the data from the Alamofire GET request. But when I make count equal to the json data given by the value method, I still return 0..What's the best way to save the values given by the GET request to local variables?

```
func loadInstallerCount() -> Int {
        var count: Int = 0
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
            //print("String:\(String(describing: response.result.value))")

            if let data = response.result.value{
                let jsonData = data as! NSDictionary
                if(!(jsonData.value(forKey: "error") as! Bool)) {
                    //getting the user from response
                    count = jsonData.value(forKey: "installationcount") as! Int
                }else{
                    //error message in case of invalid credential
                    print("couldn't get count")
                }
            }
        }
        return count
    }
```

Comment: What is the value contained by `installationcount`? Can you show us your json response.

Comment: "installationcount": 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use closure for that purpose as it is asynchronous. Example:

```
func callTheFunction(){
    loadInstallerCount { (count) in
        print(count)
    }
}

func loadInstallerCount(result:(_:Int) -> Void) {
    var count: Int = 0
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
        //print("String:\(String(describing: response.result.value))")

        if let data = response.result.value{
            let jsonData = data as! NSDictionary
            if(!(jsonData.value(forKey: "error") as! Bool)) {
                //getting the user from response
                count = jsonData.value(forKey: "installationcount") as! Int
            }else{
                //error message in case of invalid credential
                print("couldn't get count")
            }
            result(count)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It prints the correct amount, 19. But how do I return the value from callTheFunction? I don't want to print it, I want to store it to pass it around a function.

Comment: Replace print inside the closure with your function and pass the count to it.